# C reading, writing, and manipulating files

Tags: c

I have one file that has got the details of the team. I need the code to read the file, and write the percentage win on a second file. I also need to search for the specifics of the team using the search functions indicated. The code is not writing to the percentage file. When the menu shows up, the contents of the first files are printed, but the code exits even before one enters search options. I am just learning C. I would love to get to know why it is not working for me.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define NUM_TEAMS 50
#define LEN_LINE 40
#define LEN_NAME 25

char Name[NUM_TEAMS][LEN_NAME] = { 0 },
    league[NUM_TEAMS][LEN_NAME],
    division[NUM_TEAMS][LEN_NAME], 
    line[LEN_LINE];

int wins[NUM_TEAMS] = { 0 }, 
    losses[NUM_TEAMS] = {0}, 
    ties[NUM_TEAMS] = {0}, 
    pWin[NUM_TEAMS] = {0};

int main (void) {

    //getting the file
    FILE *filePtr;
    filePtr = fopen ("NFLStandings_20171031.txt", "r");
    if (filePtr == NULL) {
        printf ("Error: File did not open");
    }

    //executing
    displayWelcome ();

    select (filePtr);

    fclose (filePtr);

    return 0;
}

void displayWelcome ()
{
    printf ("............WElCOME TO THE FOOTBALL ANALYSIS.............\n\n\n\n");
}

//read file
void readFile (FILE * filePtr)
{
    int index = 0, count;

    while (index < NUM_TEAMS && fgets (line, sizeof (line), filePtr) != NULL) {
        sscanf (line, "%s%s%s%i%i%i", Name[index], league[index],
                division[index], &wins[index], &losses[index], &ties[index]);
        printf ("%s team in %s league and  %s division has won [%i] "
                "losing [%i] and tied in [%i] times \n",
                Name[index], league[index], division[index], wins[index],
                losses[index], ties[index]);
        index++;
    }

}

//find by name
void searchName (char name[], FILE * filePtr)
{
    int index = 0;

    while (index < NUM_TEAMS && fgets (line, sizeof (line), filePtr) != NULL) {
        sscanf (line, "%s%s%s%i%i%i", Name[index], league[index],
                division[index], &wins[index], &losses[index], &ties[index]);
        if (Name[index] == name) {
            printf ("The following team has the name");
            printf ("%s team in %s league and  %s division has won [%i] "
                    "losing [%i] and tied in [%i] times \n",
                    Name[index], league[index], division[index], wins[index],
                    losses[index], ties[index]);
            index++;
        }
    }
    if (index == 0)
        printf ("Sorry! No teams Found with such name");
}

//find by league
void searchLeague (char league1[], FILE * filePtr)
{
    int index = 0;

    while (index < NUM_TEAMS && fgets (line, sizeof (line), filePtr) != NULL) {
        sscanf (line, "%s%s%s%i%i%i", Name[index], league[index],
                division[index], &wins[index], &losses[index], &ties[index]);
        if (league[index] == league1) {
            printf ("The League has the following teams");
            printf ("%s team in %s league and  %s division has won [%i] "
                    "losing [%i] and tied in [%i] times \n",
                    Name[index], league[index], division[index], wins[index],
                    losses[index], ties[index]);
            index++;
        }
    }
    if (index == 0)
        printf ("Sorry! No teams Found with such League  name");
}

//search by percentage win
void searchpWin (char pWin_[], FILE * filePtr)
{
    int index = 0;

    while (index < NUM_TEAMS && fgets (line, sizeof (line), filePtr) != NULL) {
        sscanf (line, "%s%s%s%i%i%i", Name[index], league[index],
                division[index], &wins[index], &losses[index], &ties[index],
                &pWin[index]);
        if (pWin[index] == pWin_) {
            printf ("The Teams with the Percentage Win are  the following ");
            printf ("%s team in %s league and  %s division has won [%i] "
                    "losing [%i] and tied in [%i] times \n",
                    Name[index], league[index], division[index], wins[index],
                    losses[index], ties[index]);
            index++;
        }
    }
    if (index == 0)
        printf ("Sorry! No teams Found with such Percentage Win");
}

void searchDivision (char division1[], FILE * filePtr)
{
    int index = 0;

    while (index < NUM_TEAMS && fgets (line, sizeof (line), filePtr) != NULL) {
        sscanf (line, "%s%s%s%i%i%i", Name[index], league[index],
                division[index], &wins[index], &losses[index], &ties[index]);
        if (division[index] == division1) {
            printf ("The Division has the following teams");
            printf ("%s team in %s league and  %s division has won [%i] "
                    "losing [%i] and tied in [%i] times \n",
                    Name[index], league[index], division[index], wins[index],
                    losses[index], ties[index]);
            index++;
        }
    }
    if (index == 0)
        printf ("Sorry! No teams Found with such Division name");
}

//selection user Menu
void select (FILE * filePtr)
{
    int selection1 = 0;
    int selection2 = 0;

    do {
        printf ("Select the options(by typing 1,2 or 3) below to proceed \n"
                " 1. Print The Teams \n 2. Search Team \n 3. Exit \n");
        selection1 = scanf ("%d", &selection1);

        //incorrect choice
        if (selection1 > 2) {
            printf ("Invalid option! Try again");

        }
        //reading file
        if (selection1 == 1) {
            readFile (filePtr);
        }
        //option 2 Search data
        if (selection1 == 2) {
            printf ("Search by :\n 1. Team Name \n 2. By league \n "
                    "3. By division \n 4. By percentage wins \n");
            selection2 = scanf ("%d", &selection2);
        }

        switch (selection2) {
            case 1:
                printf ("Team name : \n");
                char name[10];
                scanf ("%c", name);

                searchName (name, filePtr);
                break;

            case 2:
                printf ("League name : \n");
                char league[10];
                scanf ("%c", league);
                searchLeague (league, filePtr);
                break;
            case 3:
                printf ("Division name : \n");
                char division[10];
                scanf ("%c", division);
                searchDivision (division, filePtr);
                break;
            case 4:
                printf ("Percentage win : \n");
                char pWin[10];
                scanf ("%c", pWin);
                searchpWin (pWin, filePtr);

                break;
            default:
                printf ("Invalid option.Try again!\n\n");
                break;
        }
    } while (selection1 == 0 || selection1 > 3);
}
```

Comment: Hint: learn how to format C code correctly.

Comment: `scanf("%c",league)` Are you sure you want to read in a single character here?

Comment: If you are compiling with `gcc` add `-Wall -Wextra` to your compile string to enable reasonable *compiler warnings*. If you are compiling with VS (`cl.exe`) add `/W3`. Do not accept code until it compiles cleanly **without** warning.

Comment: In addition to a complete failure to provide function prototypes visible to `main()` (e.g. you must provide a prototype for each function **before** `main()`), you have `8` significant warnings/errors that impact the function of your code. (all easily recognized if compiled with *warnings enabled*). Further if `fopen` fails, you continue to execute your code, `return 1;` on failure. Do not use *global variables*, declare in `main` and pass as a parameter as needed. (this will avoid `league` `division` and `pWin` being **shadowed** in your code.) Add `-Wshadow` to compile string.

Comment: Thank you for that.I am looking at it.

Comment: Your code does not contain operations related to _2nd file_.

Answer (score 1):

It has already been mentioned in the comments that you should always put function prototypes before the main() function and that you should return with some error code(etc. -1) when file hasn't been opened correctly.

Your select function is a total mess. DON'T do that to get user input:

```
    selection1 = scanf ("%d", &selection1);
```

The scanf function returns the total number of characters written, or a negative number. So what you've done is to assign the return value of scanf to selection1. In your case "Select the options(by typing 1,2 or 3)", wheter you type 1,2 or 3, selection1 will always be 1 as you've written 1 character. What you should have done is:

```
    scanf ("%d", &selection1);
```

Now going into the switch statement...

```
scanf ("%c", name);
```

The latter statement "%c" reads a single character. But you don't want a single character, right? You want a string, so maybe try this instead:

```
scanf ("%s", name);
```

Moreover, this whole switch statement for selection2 is completely pointless unless selection1 is 2, so maybe executing it only then will be a good idea.

Going into the search functions:

```
if (Name[index] == name)
```

The latter compares references, not the actual values. So you might wanna do some research about the strcmp() function and use it there.

You might as well think about you exit condition in the do-while loop in select function. You've said  "1. Print The Teams \n 2. Search Team \n 3. Exit \n" so maybe you should terminate the loop once somebody enters 3?

Anyway, I've noted some of the most crucial mistakes, and with some more effort you might be able to make your code work, as this is not a place where someone will do it for you, but rather will give you some advice and hints. I really recommend you, however, to once again go through the basics of the C programming language. When I started learning it(like 2 years ago) as a beginner I found extremely helpful the "Teach Yourself C" by Herbert Schildt. You might wanna give it a try.